# Numerical evaluation of the value of a non-elementary function

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, gaussian-integral

Let f(x)= $\int e^{-x^2}dx$

Is there any way to calculate the value of f(z) for any real number z? For example f(1), f(2.3), f(-3), etc.?

Comment: Do you mean rather, $f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-u^2} du $?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to compute (approximate) values.  Look up [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).